# On the non Hausdorff-ness of projective variety

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb P^n$ denote a projective variety. When $X$ is a Hausdorff space (we're talking about $X$ as about a topological space with Zariski topology)?

Almost never, I believe: only if $X$ is finite.

I need this fact to finish a simple proof but I haven't any ideas on how to prove it.

Comment: almost never, I believe. Only if $X$ is finite?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, I think that it's the most plausible answer. But I haven't any arguments...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've updated my question.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If $X$ is Hausdorff, then points are closed. We may as well work with $X^\mathrm{red}$ since this doesn't change the topological space. And we may as well work with an irreducible component. Then, $X$ is integral and all points are closed. In particular, the generic point is closed. This implies that $k(\eta)/k$ is finite so $\mathrm{tr.deg}(k(\eta)/k)=0$ so $\dim X=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Irreducible varieties $X$ always have generic points: *i.e.* a point $x_0\in X$ such that $\{x_0\}$ is dense in $X$. If $X$ was Hausdorff, then $\{x_0\}$ would also be closed, so $X=\{x_0\}$ is a singleton.

If $X$ is not irreducible, apply this to each irreducible component, so that $X$ is finite and discrete.